# Forge Viewer multi-model context and pivot point

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have a multi-model loaded into the viewer. The coordinate systems of the models are similar, with no major deviations. All tools appear to be working normally.

The pivot point appears to update annoyingly as the viewer state changes. For example, when the user zooms with the mouse wheel, the pivot point moves somewhere outside the screen. The WheelSetsPivot setting does not fix the problem. Viewer version is 7. We have tried many viewer versions without any luck.

When loading only one model into the viewer pivot point works as expected.

How can I fix this to work like one-model case? Any settings for multi-model context or for pivot point?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the viewer's old style aggregate view init (viewer version 6?) for multi-model context. When I updated multi-model loading to v7 style (loadDocumentNode), everything seems to be working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the situation you addressed, you mean when user is zooming and another model is loaded, the camera will move to somewhere, right?

If so, haven't you included `preserveView: true` in the `loadModelOptions` when calling Viewer3D#loadDocumentNode?  This option can prevent Forge Viewer from auto-resetting camera state automatically on adding a new model to the scene.

```js
const loadModelOptions = {
  keepCurrentModels: true,
  preserveView: true,
  // ...
};

viewer.loadDocumentNode( doc, viewalbe, loadModelOptions );
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in commenting. We have loaded models successfully and the model hierarchy is in order. The problem occurs when the user zooms in or out with the mouse wheel. Then the pivot point always moves somewhere other than what the user has set. I've debugged the location of the pivot point and it's really moving.